# WCF chat / game server - client shutdown

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, client-server, chat

Anyone who has ever built a chat room / a game with WCF server as the back-end

How did you handle situation that a client is being shutdown (being terminated unexpectedly) without nicely exiting / logging out, making the server know that this client "has left" the room / game / whatever

This question bothers me a lot these days when I am developing a Turn-base card game with room and if I kill client process while he is inside a room I as a server can not know about this and create a notification that will be polled by other clients about the gone client.

**I can be creative** and think about the solution of sending the server every [second] that I am still connected. When a second passes without getting this "I'm still alive!" packet the server will regrettably declare about the death of a client R.I.P...

Honestly - I think that this solution will make my server die before being able to declare about the death of any other client (the amount of requests every second he will need to handle)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a background service on the server side which runs every x seconds and calls the list of clients. If the client is disconnected/does not respond, you can update the status of the client as disconnected.

Comment: Problem is that the clients are not servers and are not connected to the server all the time... Instead they are making http GET / POST requests to preform operations on or get data from the server

Answer (score 0):

Create session that will be disappear after specific time
and update specific session when specific client access server